# Trying to add string objects into a linked list in alphabetical order by using compareTo but I am stuck on inserting elements in the middle. Java

Tags: java, linked-list, compareto

```
public void addElement(Object element)
{
    if(first == null) //empty list 
    {
        addFirst(element);
    }
    else 
    {
        //having these move
        boolean cloud = true;
        LinkedListIterator hamsters = new LinkedListIterator();
        while (hamsters.hasNext() && cloud) //while there are elements in the list.
        {
            //getting strings to compare
            String str = (String) element; //string entered
            System.out.println(str +" is string I just entered");
            String str2 = (String) hamsters.next();
            System.out.println(str2 +" is string inside the list");

            //if string entered is greater than second string, then insert new node. 
            if(str.compareTo(str2) > 0 || str.compareTo(str2) == 0)
            {
                hamsters.add(element);
                cloud = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem with this code is that it only compares with the first element (and inserts the element after the first element) in the linked list. So if I enter something like "apple, banana, cat", it will print "apple, cat, banana," when I need it to print, "apple, banana, cat."

Any suggestions?

Edit: Here's the iterator --> https://gist.github.com/bettyjing/84ee94b73713226ba8ad

Comment: It looks like your `LinkedListIterator hamsters` isn't actually pointing to any list?

Comment: What is the class `LinkedListIterator`? Apparently, `hamsters.add(element)` will add the element *after* the current element, but it is difficult to say how to solve this without seeing what it does.

Comment: Sorry, here's the class: https://gist.github.com/bettyjing/84ee94b73713226ba8ad

Answer (score 1):

You should not be inserting the a new node right after the first element in the list that is less than the new one. You should be inserting it **before** the first element in the list that is greater than the new one (or at the end if none in the list is greater).

Try this:

```
while (hamsters.hasNext() && cloud) //while there are elements in the list.
{
    //getting strings to compare
    String str = (String) element; //string entered
    System.out.println(str +" is string I just entered");
    String str2 = (String) hamsters.next();
    System.out.println(str2 +" is string inside the list");

    //if string entered is less than second string, then insert new node before it. 
    if(str.compareTo(str2) < 0 || str.compareTo(str2) == 0)
    {
        hamsters.previous();
        hamsters.add(element);
        cloud = false;
    }
}
if (cloud) 
{
    hamster.add(element);
}
```

Comment: The OP says that it's only comparing to the first elements of the list. So either the OP's test cases only used a few elements or there's something else going on...

Comment: Even if there wasn't something else going on, his code would always stop at the first element in the list that is less that the new element without checking if the new element should be placed even further back in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `LinkedListIterator` never actually gets initialized. You start with

```
  position = null;
  previous = null;
```

and you never actually set them to anything in the code I see. On the other hand, if that's the problem then your loop should just quit immediately, so is there something else going on?